# Programmatically add XsltListViewWebPart to Community Homepage

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, discussion-board, community-site, ssom

As you may know, when you create a Community site, it automatically creates a discussion list which is added to `/SitePages/Community Home.aspx` which looks like so.

[image]

I am trying to replace this with another list that I have created programmatically and have it look just like the image above.

This is what I have attempted:

```
//Get the community homepage.
SPFile communityHomepage = web.GetFile("/SitePages/Community Home.aspx");
SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = communityHomepage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

//Index 0 contains the default discussion board list for a community site template.
webPartManager.WebParts[0].AllowClose = true;

//Close the default list web part.
webPartManager.CloseWebPart(webPartManager.WebParts[0]);
webPartManager.SaveChanges(webPartManager.WebParts[0]); 
//Get my list that I want to replace it with.
SPList discList = web.Lists[discBoardName];

XsltListViewWebPart listViewWebPart = new XsltListViewWebPart();
listViewWebPart.ListId = discList.ID; 
listViewWebPart.ListName = discList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
listViewWebPart.Title = discBoardName;
listViewWebPart.ClientRender = true;
listViewWebPart.Toolbar = "Standard";
SPView view = discList.Views["Subject"];
listViewWebPart.ViewId = int.Parse(view.BaseViewID);
listViewWebPart.XmlDefinition = view.GetViewXml();
webPartManager.AddWebPart(listViewWebPart, "Main", 0);
webPartManager.SaveChanges(listViewWebPart);
discList.Update();
listViewWebPart.Dispose();
webPartManager.Dispose();
```

The default list webpart view is closed fine, but the one I am trying to add is added outside of the page layout all the way at the bottom and does not look like I want it to.

[image]

I have also tried using

```
string zoneId = webPartManager.GetZoneID(webPartManager.WebParts[0]);
```

and passing `zoneId` to `AddWebPart()`, but that didn't work either. So how do I add this List to the page in the correct location with the correct aesthetic look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shailen Sukul](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/7074/shailen-sukul) has a great example posted on the MSDN forums.  I suggest you start there first.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54d780ea-df2f-408d-9056-cf6f0c27f04e/add-xsltlistviewwebpart-via-code?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: The web part aesthetically looks the way I want it to, however, the web part is still not being placed in the correct zone on the page. I would have thought `string zoneId = webPartManager.GetZoneID(webPartManager.WebParts[0]);` would allow me to place it correctly, but `zoneId` contains value of `"wpz"` which does not seem like any specific web part zone. Any thoughts on finding the correct zone for a community page?

Comment: Figured out the placement. I am adding the webpart to a "Rich Content" webpart so there is a little hacking needed. Please reference http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-adding-web-parts-rich-content-sharepoint-2010/